# UltraTabControl resize image

Tags: vb.net, image, tabcontrol, infragistics, image-size

Here is my question
I have ultratabcontrol (infragistics's control) in my project with six tab pages in it. Each of tab pages contains imagelist with 5 images (.ico). 4 images have size 32x32 and one i made 60x60. 32x32 is really too small for me. but when i run project my 60x60 image has the same width and height with other four images. i tried to set image's size in ImageList object but it doesn't help. so could you please provide me some links or help me if you know what's wrong?

Comment: What are you using to display the image?